# Simple API's to play around with for Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, api

Does anyone know of simple and well documented API's with plenty of hand holding examples that assumes very little or no prior knowledge of web development?

I've been messing around with Pyfacebook and Facebook-Python-SDK in trying to create a simple photo display app but I haven't been able to make much headway after spending the last few days on it. The main reason for this is simply because I just wasn't able to find a good tutorial that walks me through all the steps. So, I'm putting this mini project on pause and looking for lower hanging fruit.

In terms of skill level, I'm pretty ok on the basics of Python and Django.

**Update**
I've done the tutorials at http://www.djangoproject.com/ already. Really looking for ideas and suggestions on webapp projects that utilises an API. E.g, a twitter app that displays a user's most frequently used keywords in a tagcloud.

**Update2**
Side note: Having mess around with Twitter's API for a little bit, I would definitely recommend to start with Twitter first as opposed to Facebook. It's easier and better documented.

Answer (score 0):

Best place to start is with tutorials on djangoproject.com.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)? It is pretty basic, but touches on all important points required to develop your own basic app.

Answer (score 0):

[django-basic-apps](https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps) contains a collection of apps you might enjoy reading.

Edit: Check out this good [list of web services](http://gulati.info/2009/11/9-ultimate-web-services-that-could-help-you-with-your-next-project/) I found. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't write facebook apps with Django. Facebook uses their own API and stuff. They are completely different.

And for the twitter API thingy I have an idea.

> Develop a django app which can used to
>   scrap and backup tweets.
>
> The scenario is during any FOSS
>   conference, they are using a #hastag
>   to identify tweets  related to that
>   conf. But after sometime these tweets
>   don't show up even on search. For
>   example we used #inpycon2010 tag for
>   Pycon conf in India. But now when I
>   search for this tag, nothing shows up.
>   So what you can do allow users to
>   register a hastag and set a time
>   interval. Within that time interval
>   your app should scrap all the tweets
>   and backup them. The user should be
>   able to retreive from that later.

If you start this a foss project, I'm ready to jump in :)

Comment: My question is not about Django or Facebook. That was just a personal experience I wanted to share. I would like to know of simple and well documented API's with plenty of hand holding examples that assumes very little or no prior knowledge of web development?